# Form field, input data stays when error occurs

Tags: php, forms

How to make already typed data not disappeared when error occurs in PHP form.

Example : if I type name and address correctly but I made mistake with email and error occurs I want correct fields stay the same, how I do that?

```
 <div class="elements">
  <label for="name">Name :</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="50" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
</div>
<div class="elements">
  <label for="e-mail">E-mail :</label>
<input type="text" id="e-mail" name="e-mail" size="50"  value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/>
</div>
<div class="elements">
  <label for="Password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" size="50" />
</div><input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="50"  " />
```

I tried echo that but when page is loaded for first time something like that is visible in form field 
**Notice**:  Undefined variable: name in **C:\xampp\htdocs\MyOnlineStore\members\index.php** on line **173**

Comment: You'll need to give us more detail and show what you tried.

Comment: I know that variable are empty so that why I get that string in filed but I have no idea how to aproach that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called sticky forms.

You are getting the error string because your variable is empty, that's right. You could simply silence them by adding an at-sign in front of your variable, but that isn't the best practice. What you need to do is check if the value exists, and display if so, or display something else if not.

I made a helper function that can check to see wether to display what has come in from $_POST or a default value. put in the input

```
event name<br />
<input type="text" 
       style="width:100%" 
       name="title" 
       value="<?=stickyRow($_POST,'title','')?>" />


function stickyRow($array,$index,$default = ''){

    if(empty($array[$index]) || $array[$index] == ''){
        return $default;
    }else{
        return $array[$index];
    }

}
```

The $array is usually the returned $_POST, $_GET or $_RESULT array. The $index is the key that belongs in that input. If that is key populated, it shows it in the form, if not, it shows a default value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: solution with @ worked, thanks a lot man. I'll tried to resolve that with function but it failed, probably because I did it wrong but I'll be trying my best to use that solution, thank you again

Comment: ok, just be careful with that '@' sign - it can make your debugging pretty tough if you use it wrong!

Comment: I will :) maybe you know how to use @ with option value where users select country ? It's not that important but I would like to learn more each time I aproach any kind of problems, cheers

Comment: I fixed if anybody will have that problem here is solution  <option value=""><?php echo @$Country?></option>

Answer (score 0):

I think for the correct input field you can save them in sessions.